# Is there a way to indicate the action to remove a manga's cover to see the hidden cover?

Tags: manga-production, terminology

Ok, maybe the question can look weird. And actually it is.
Let me explain further: a friend of mine removes a lot of times covers from his manga (tankōbon). I don't mean that he actually rips off the cover from the manga, but he removes the dust jacket (or, for me, the first layer) of the colored cover. Under this dust jacket, sometimes, there is another hidden non-colored cover page, that shows the author's easter eggs.

I don't have pictures now, but, for example, it happens with some volumes of Monster Musume and Made in Abyss. As Aki Tanaka said in the comment, [One Piece also has this kind of easter eggs](https://blog-imgs-31-origin.fc2.com/g/o/g/gogohappyday/20111110220206242.jpg).

I didn't find anything about this on the web, and no one talks about it.
So I was asking: is there a term to describe this practice? Is it frequent to do it among collectors?
I am just curious to know about this.